# Accessing json object in angular 4 and displaying it in html

Tags: json, angular, angular5

I have a json object as follows.

```
{
  "CandidateSchemaRows": [
    {
      "Description": "sadasd",
      "Experience": 1,
      "type": "selectbox"
    },
    {
      "Description": "erwerw",
      "Experience": 2,
      "type": "selectbox"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to print it in html page with the help of typescript. What should be the approach in ts file?

Answer (score 1):

use ngFor

```
 <ul *ngFor="let pers of result?.CandidateSchemaRows">
        <li>
            {{pers.Description}} {{pers.Age}} {{pers.Experience}}     
        </li>
  </ul>
```

**[DEMO STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g24nwz?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: I think it's result['CandidateSchemaRows'] not result.CandidateSchemaRows to avoid any error of unknown property

Comment: I added safe navigation operator

Answer (score 1):

Code for the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my-template.html'
})
export class MyComponent {
  let myObj = {
    "CandidateSchemaRows": [
      {
        "Description": "sadasd",
        "Experience": 1,
        "type": "selectbox"
      },
      {
        "Description": "erwerw",
        "Experience": 2,
        "type": "selectbox"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<p>{{myObj.CandidateSchemaRows}}</p>
```

[Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data)

Answer (score 1):

in ts file

```
let data = {
  "CandidateSchemaRows": [
    {
      "Description": "sadasd",
      "Experience": 1,
      "type": "selectbox"
    },
    {
      "Description": "erwerw",
      "Experience": 2,
      "type": "selectbox"
    }
  ]
}
```

and in HTML

```
<ul *ngFor="let values of data?.CandidateSchemaRows;let i=index">
        <li>
            <div class="description">{{values.Description}} of {{i}}</div>
            <div class="Experience">{{values.Experience}} of {{i}}</div>
            <div class="type">{{values.type}} of {{i}}</div>     
        </li>
  </ul>
```